# Jquery placing an icon gallery within a accordion

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, accordion, image-gallery

I am looking for a jquery accordion plugin where each panel within the accordion can contain a draggable icon gallery.

Answer (score 0):

I recently made a draggable icon that animated an accordian effect on hover to display information about that icon, then once the user is sure to choose that , the user could drag it in to phone simulator that generated a screen shot of what that module could like. I hope this helps.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var dragged = false;
    /////////////BUTTON HOVER ACTION

    $('[class$="Button"]').mousedown(function() {
        dragged = true;
    });

    $('[class$="Button"]').mouseup(function() {
        dragged = false;

    });

    $('[class$=Button]').mouseover(function() {

        var arr = $(this).attr('class').split("Button");
        //alert(arr[0]);
        if (!dragged) {
            //$('[class$=Content]').hide();
            //$('[class$=Content]').dequeue("fx");
            $('div.'+arr[0]+'Content').stop(true, true).slideDown('slow');

        }
    });



    /////////////BUTTON HOVEROUT ACTION 

    $('[class$=Button]').mouseout(function() {

        var arr = $(this).attr('class').split("Button");
        //alert(arr[0]);
        $('div.'+arr[0]+'Content').stop(true, true).slideUp('slow');
        //$('[class$=Content]').hide();

    });
/////////////hide on Doc Load 

  $('[class$=Content]').hide();

});
```